# combining log likelihoods from different series of observations

Tags: hidden-markov-model, expectation-maximization, likelihood, baum-welch

I have generated multiple log likelihood estimates for some parameters $\theta$ based on independent sets of observation. How can I combine these into one average?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the data sets are independent, summing the likelihoods would give the total log likelihood of $\theta$ in the combined data set. This is because the joint density (or mass function) of independent random variables is the product of the individual densities (or mass functions). See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_probability_distribution#Joint_distribution_for_independent_variables) for more info.